# Add Communication Notification capability in my Notification Service Extension's Info.plist swift

Tags: swift

How can I added the Communication Notification capability, and in my Notification Service Extension's Info.plist in swift ?

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?

    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
       

        let avatar = INImage(named: "Cover")

        let senderPerson = INPerson(personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: "1233211234", type: .unknown), nameComponents: personNameComponents, displayName: "Sender Name", image: avatar, contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil, isMe: false, suggestionType: .none)

        let mePerson = INPerson( personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: "1233211232", type: .unknown), nameComponents: nil, displayName: nil, image: nil, contactIdentifier: nil, customIdentifier: nil, isMe: true, suggestionType: .none)

        let incomingMessagingIntent = INSendMessageIntent(recipients: [mePerson], outgoingMessageType: .outgoingMessageText, content: "Test DUde", speakableGroupName: nil, conversationIdentifier: "uid", serviceName: "caset", sender: senderPerson, attachments: [])

        incomingMessagingIntent.setImage(avatar, forParameterNamed: \.sender)

        let interaction = INInteraction(intent: incomingMessagingIntent, response: nil)

        interaction.direction = .incoming

        do {

            let newContent = try request.content.updating(from: incomingMessagingIntent)

            contentHandler(newContent)

        } catch {

            print(error)

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class name of each intent that your app supports to the NSUserActivityTypes array in your Info.plist. To support INSendMessageIntent donations.
[image]